# execute a query which is stored as column in another table using PHP and oracle database

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a bunch of sql queries stored in a column of an oracle database table. I have to retrieve one query at a time, execute it and display the results of this query on the front end. Here is the first query in the QUERY column.

```
select a.division_id, a.completion_id, a.num_of_stages, b.num_of_stages as numb,     abs(a.num_of_stages - b.num_of_stages) as diff from odm_dba.odm_comp_summary a, (select    division_id, completion_id, count(*) num_of_stages from odm_dba.odm_comp_stage group by     division_id, completion_id) b where a.division_id = b.division_id and a.completion_id =     b.completion_id and a.num_of_stages <> b.num_of_stages;
```

I executed this code in toad. It was working fine. No I am using the below code to retrieve the QUERY column and then execute it.

```
<?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$qry = "SELECT query FROM vdc_dba.queries";
$result = oci_parse($conn, $qry);
oci_execute($result);

$row = oci_fetch_array($result);
echo $row['QUERY'];
$new_result=oci_parse($conn,$row['QUERY']);
oci_execute($new_result);
$row1 = oci_fetch_array($new_result);
echo $row1['DIVISION_ID'];
```

?>

This is the output of the above query

" The actual query and then
Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in C:\xampp\htdocs\query.php on line 13

Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\xampp\htdocs\query.php on line 14"

I am not sure how to use the result of a query as a query again. I am new to PHP, any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: At a minimum, get rid of the `.`s on the last row and end the statement with a semicolon (`;`). Otherwise, you will have syntax errors.

Comment: I forgot to add the semicolon in the code here. I want to know the steps to follow after retrieving this column. How can I use the retrieved QUERY column as a query again?

Comment: Just pass the value in `$row['QUERY']` back to the database. Something like this: `$new_result = oci_parse($conn, $row['QUERY']);`

Comment: Also, I'm still not sure why you have periods in the last line of your code, but they will definitely cause a parser error. If you're still having problems, please post your actual code, including the semicolon and everything.

Comment: <?php 
session_start();
ob_start();
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

$qry = "SELECT query FROM queries";
$result = oci_parse($conn, $qry);
oci_execute($result);

 $row = oci_fetch_array($result);
 echo $row['QUERY'];
 $new_result=oci_parse($conn,$row['QUERY']);
 oci_execute($new_result);
 $row1 = oci_fetch_array($new_result);
 echo $row1['DIVISION_ID'];
?>

Comment: I tweaked the code based on your suggestions. First part of the query works just fine. I am able to display the query via the echo statement. 

Second part of the query gives me the following error. 

Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in C:\xampp\htdocs\query.php on line 13

and

Warning: oci_fetch_array(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\xampp\htdocs\query.php on line 14

Comment: That is a syntax problem with the query you're trying to execute, which you haven't posted. Please edit your question with (1) the query that is stored in the table and (2) all of the relevant PHP code.

Comment: Got it resolved. I had a semi colon at the end of the query inside the column. Its working fine now. Thanks a lot for your help @EdCottrell.